# Azure DevOps -Get details of users accessing the git repo including clone

Tags: git, azure-devops

We want to check the activities of people accessing the Azure DevOps git repository, something like github traffic, but with bit more information such as the individual user details and what they did, like, clone, visited a specific page or pushed some changes etc.

Is there a log available in Azure DevOPs.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a log available in Azure DevOPs to check the activities of people accessing the Azure DevOps git repository.

As I know this is **not supported** yet. We can only see Push/PR related events in Web portal instead of in log. And action like cloning the repos is not recorded.

For now Azure Devops Service provides [audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page) to monitor many changes that occur throughout an Azure DevOps organization. You can find this option in `Organization Settings => Auditing`, according to the [latest document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/azure-devops-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page#areas), the option only supports areas like:

```
Git:    Create, delete, modify, bypass PR policy, and delete Git repo.
Git:    Branch policies, and create, delete, and rename repository.
```

The `modify` in first line doesn't contain events like push code and clone repos, it's just something occurs when creating new repos:

[image]

**Ps:** I've checked and confirmed that logs about `clone/push/visit repos page` events are not recorded as the document states.

**Summary:**

To know the user who makes actions like Push/PR/Commits/Add Tag, you have to navigate to the Azure Devops Repos page and check the info there in :

[image]

But for the info about who clones the repos, I'm afraid we can't see this info even in UI page. Hope my answer helps to resolve your puzzle :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In GitHub, they got something called traffic which has some information about the activities as per this https://github.blog/2014-08-12-clone-graphs/. Is there something similar in Azure DevOps?