# Can i see history copy repo azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to know if there is one way to know how many times my Repo in Azure DevOps was Copied, Or How to know who copied my Repo in my Organization Project.

There is one way to know about this?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. At the moment, there does not seem to be a way to track the number of times that a repository has been cloned in Azure DevOps.

This post has more information as well: [Azure DevOps -Get details of users accessing the git repo including clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60863047/azure-devops-get-details-of-users-accessing-the-git-repo-including-clone).